# CSS: Fallback fonts

Tags: css, fonts

My website uses a rather obscure font that about half the computers can properly read. The font is "Lucida Console".
On the computers that can't read this font, they get displayed ugly Times New Roman, is there a way to set the font of my website to Lucida Console but on computers that can't read it, view Arial instead? Using CSS.

Comment: This “rather obscure font” you’re talking about? It’s included in every copy of Windows.

Comment: not sure why it only displays in some computers (all windows)

Comment: oh my mistake, the font name is "ocr a std"

Comment: an easy mistake to make. The names sound almost identical. :-p

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can specify multiple fonts:

```
p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

The browser will try the first one, if that one isn't available the second, and so forth. In the end it uses the family serif, so the browser chooses any serif font. You should use the monospace family.

So in your case, something like this is what you want:

```
p {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

Comment: p{font-family:"Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;}
So this right here picks Lucida Console but falls back to Courier New if not available? Also, care to enlighten me what adding monospace does?

Comment: @Kevin: it means to fall back on the system’s default monospace fonts if none of the previous fonts is available. However, use this feature with care (read: not at all) because Safari will use it as a hint to adapt the font size of style, making it smaller. And there’s virtually no way to prevent this without setting a fixed font size (which is extremely bad style and will transport you directly into Dante’s Limbo).

Comment: @Rudolph, very nice info. Another question: having font-family:"ocr a std", "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace; will this be 3 fallback fonts?

Comment: @KevinDuke Yes, it'll fall back in the order you have specified.

Answer (score 9):

Further tips:

- Google [css font stack](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=css%20font%20stack&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for suggested lists of fonts aimed at certain styles of fonts. 'font stack' is the colloquial name for these font lists.
- Think cross-platform. Consider adding fonts commonly found on [Mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X), [Linux](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/a-web-designers-guide-to-linux-fonts/), [iOS](http://www.iosfonts.com), Android, Windows, and other platforms your readers may be using.
- Always include a [generic-family](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families) name at the end of your font stack in case the user has none of your desired fonts:

  - *serif*
  - *sans-serif*
  - *cursive*
  - *fantasy*
  - *monospace*
- Include quotes around fonts named with multiple words, or simply quote all font names.

Comment: One more tip: [some gliphs are missing in Google fonts](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/issues/617), like box drawing. Adobe's [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro) and [Mononoki](https://madmalik.github.io/mononoki/) are good workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

You can also serve that obscure font with your website (if you are legally able to) using @font-face. It's easy and works even in IE6 :).

Read about it here: http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/

Comment: Since this thread might still be active( has a average of 6 views per days), I'd just like to extend your comment and say STOP developing for IE6 ;)

Comment: @cammy Unless you work for the Chinese market ;). By the way, the important point in my answer is not IE6 of course.