# How to apply a fallback font?

Tags: css, fonts, fallback

```
body {
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

body {
font-family: sans-serif; 
}
```

This is my CSS now. I've read that if you put your fallback font second, it'll only be used on devices your first font doesn't work on.

However, on my laptop, it chooses to show the fallback font (It does read the first font when the fallback is out of my CSS). How do I apply a fallback font without it -ruining- my page?

Comment: Important technical detail: you *don't* have two fonts in your first `body` block. You have one font, `Ubuntu` (which doesn't need quotes btw since it has no non-alphanumeric characters in the name), and you have a *generic font class*. "sans-serif" is not a font, it's a special keyword that tells the browser "you know what? Pick **any** font that has a sans-serif category bit set, I don't even care which one you pick". That said, look at your code and then ask yourself "what happens when I set `font-family` and then I set it again".

Comment: see the accepted answer of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673963/css-fallback-fonts

Answer (score 9):

Remove the second block.

You are already defining `sans-serif` as a fallback. If you wish to add another font, Arial for example, just add it to the comma separated list:

```
body {
    font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

In this example, if Ubuntu is not installed, Arial will be used. If Arial is not installed, the systems default sans-serif font will be used.

What you are doing in your example is *overriding* the first style block with the second which is why `sans-serif` is always used and the first block is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have to provide them in one single line of CSS, like this:

```
body {
    font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, 'Your font', sans-serif;
}
```

It's the order of fonts that decides what font to use. Stating `body` for a second time will override the first one. Read more about `font-family` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).

Comment: no reason to quote Ubuntu, there are no characters in it that require quoting (obviously "your font" does need the quotes)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Just copy/paste it from the question, but good point. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `body/font-family`rule *overwrites* the first one, so the browser won't ever fetch the fonts listed in the first rule.

Just remove the second rule and add the fallback font to your first rule, as second in your list of fonts (`'Ubuntu', Arial, sans-serif;`).