# font-family: "AvantGarde"; in CSS

Tags: html, css, adobe, font-family

I am working on an image in Adobe Photoshop. The CSS codes which I am getting for the same image from the Adobe Photoshop are:

CSS

```
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "AvantGarde";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.792;
  text-align: left;
 -moz-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 690.337px;
  top: 322.77px;
  z-index: 103;
```

I am wondering, how can I put  font-family: AvantGarde in my CSS codes. For some reasons, I cant find this in my CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure to include a link to the font in the css using `@font-face`?
i.e.

```
body { /* this will apply to the whole body tag */
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    font-size: 25px; 
    font-family: "AvantGarde"; 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    line-height: 1.792; 
    text-align: left; 
    -moz-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0); 
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0); 
    -ms-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}
```

Photoshop uses the fonts installed on the system, to include other fonts in css on a website you need to link to the .woff file. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: @I am very much new to font-face so in the above code (in my question) it will go something like this ?
`p
{
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}
 font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "AvantGarde";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.792;
  text-align: left;
 -moz-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633,0,0,1.66565153423699,0,0);
 }`

Comment: If this is on a website you will need to upload the AvantGarde.woff file so that it can be accessed i.e https://yoursite.com/AvantGarde.woff see my edit on where to put the @font-face

Comment: Can we use this `font-family: AvantGarde Demo` in our body tags(like above) by using the same `@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}`

Comment: Do you mean you want to apply it to a `<div>` with the class demo? in which case you would replace the `body {` with `.demo {` as per regular css, or do you want to specify a fallback font of Demo if AvantGarde is not available as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673963/css-fallback-fonts? I'm still unsure of your goals.

Comment: @No I think you didn't get my question. There is a `font-family: AvantGarde Demo` . My question is, can we use it in the body tags above by using the `@font-face { font-family: AvantGarde; src: url(AvantGarde.woff); }`

Comment: Sorry yes you can't have spaces in font names you will need to wrap it in speech marks `font-family: "AvantGarde Demo"` you will also need to create a separate @font-face for it i.e `@font-face { font-family: AvantGarde; src: url("AvantGarde Demo.woff");}`. Please tell me if I'm understanding this correctly

Comment: @ Yes you got my question. Just checking one more time, In font family it should be `AvantGarde` not AvantGarde Demo `@font-face { font-family: AvantGarde; src: url("AvantGarde Demo.woff");}`

Comment: I would say so yes, without trying it myself. It's quite easy to test both so

Comment: For this `font-family: “ITC Avant Garde Gothic”;`  I should use `@font-face {
    font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
    src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}`
?  Let me know if I am wrong.