# How are emojis represented when a font on specified

Tags: unicode, emoji

When I specify a specific font to use (especially for text on a webpage), regardless of which one, will emojis generally always display properly?

*Are emojis part of the font you specify*, or does the operating system or application use the font you designate, *except for certain code points which represent emojis* (and use something internal for them)?

Also, are these rules and emojis in general limited to Unicode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Fallback fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673963/css-fallback-fonts)

Comment: Not entirely, fallback font is still something I can specify, now how the os is handling it as a rule, but ty for suggesting

Comment: I'm curious about this question too.